# php counter going crazy with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use `.htaccess` to make pretty URLs for my site. Here's the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /post\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /post/%1/%2$ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

And inside my `post.php` page, I have a simple view counter:

```
$url = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1);
$url = explode('/',$url);
$id_post = $purifier->purify($url[1]);
$post = $db->selectone("select p.*, u.username from tx_post p inner join user u on p.id_user = u.id_user where id_post = :id_post",[':id_post'=>$id_post]);

echo 'VIEWS:'.$post['views'].'<br>';
$views = $post['views']+1;
echo 'views after:'.$views.'<br>';
$db->update('tx_post',['views'=>$views],'id_post='.$id_post);
```

Now here is my problem: when I go to the URL `example.com/post/78` (without the final slash) everything works fine. The counter gets what's in the database and increment by 1 just like it should. However, if I put the final slash (`example.com/post/78/`), the counter increments 26. Obviously the same thing happens when I pass another parameter (like how I intend to do - `example.com/post/78/postname/`).

The counter doesn't have any other increment on the page, so I'm assuming it's executing the page multiple times (if that's even possible, I don't know much about web servers).

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any good reason in the code you posted why the counter should be going crazy like that? Do you have other directives? However, the `.htaccess` directives you've posted would not be getting processed at all for a request like `/post/78` or `/post/78/`. This suggests MultiViews is enabled. Also, why are you extracting the id from the REQUEST_URI, when you are supposedly passing this in the URL parameter? This also suggests MultiViews is taking over. You'll need MultiViews disabled for these directives to function as intended. ie. `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: @MrWhite it worked! I'm just beginning with htaccess, so I don't know much about it and I've never heard about this MultiViews option.
The REQUEST_URI is something I was trying to use before using .htaccess, but I just forgot to change it back. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Glad that helped. I've added my comment, with some additional explanation, as an answer - if you can "accept" it (tick/checkmark on the left below the voting arrows) that would be great (helps other readers and removes the question from the unanswered question queue). Once you have 15+rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Although simply disabling MultiViews alone wouldn't necessarily create a working script, since the directives you've posted don't appear to match a request of the form `/post/78`? I've addressed this in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any good reason in the code you posted why the counter should be going crazy like that? However, the `.htaccess` directives you've posted would not be getting processed at all for a request like `example.com/post/78` (no slash) or `example.com/post/78/` (with slash) - the regex simply does not match. This suggests `MultiViews` is enabled.

Also, it seems odd that you extracting the `id` from the `REQUEST_URI` server variable when you are supposedly passing this in the URL parameter? This also suggests `MultiViews` is taking over. You'll need `MultiViews` disabled for these directives to function as intended. At the top of your `.htaccess` file you should add the following:

```
# Disable MultiViews
Options -MultiViews
```

Since `/post/78` maps directly to a file of the same name but with a `.php` extension then with `MultiViews` enabled mod_negotiation ends up issuing an internal subrequest for `/post.php` - without any URL parameters.

Note that the directives you posted only appear to match URLs of the form `/post/<id>/<postname>` (with or without the trailing slash). To match `/post/<id>` only, you'll need an additional directive, or modify your existing directive to match both.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?/?$ post.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```